# how to create a stacked barpot side by side per group within another group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a comparison of the 3 datasets that has stacked groupings, however, my codes keeps stacking the group as well.

this is how I wanted it to look like:

[image]

Thank you!

For example, I have this data set:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  value = c(3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 7, 8, 7, 8),
  type = c("a1", "b1", "c1", "c2", "a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "b1", "b2", "c1", "a1", "a2", "a3"),
  group = c("groupA", "groupB", "groupC", "groupC", "groupA", "groupA", "groupB", "groupB", "groupB", "groupB", "groupC", "groupA", "groupB", "groupC")
)
```

and my code is this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill = type, x = id, y = value, group = group)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("a1" = "#00acee", "a2" = "#3e89ac", "b1" = "#f4821e", "b2" = "#c36818", "c1" = "#49cd83", "c2" = "#169a50")) +
  theme_classic()
```

but the plot I keep getting is this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use faceting to achieve your desired result, i.e. facet by `id`, map `group` on `x` and use `group=1`. And for the final look move the strip text to the bottom, set the panel spacing to zero and remove the x axis text, ticks, ... .

Note: There is probably a typo in your example data, i.e. there is a `type="a3"`. Hence we get a grey bar.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(fill = type, x = group, y = value, group = 1)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      "a1" = "#00acee", "a2" = "#3e89ac",
      "b1" = "#f4821e", "b2" = "#c36818",
      "c1" = "#49cd83", "c2" = "#169a50"
    )
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~id, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background.x = element_rect(color = NA),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.length.x = unit(0, "pt"),
    panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That works really well. Can you also happen to know how to remove the space between the bars so they're positioned tightly side by side?

Comment: Be aware that `position="dodge"` will not stack the bars. But to remove the space between the bars you are right with using `width=1` i.e. do `geom_col(width = 1)`